# How does mapA work with a Stream Function Arrow in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, arrows

## Background

I've been going through John Hughes' [Programming with Arrows](http://www.cse.chalmers.se/~rjmh/afp-arrows.pdf), and I felt that I had everything straight in my head until the following example of using mapA:

```
>runSF (mapA (delay 0)) [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
[[0,0,0],[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
```

Where runSF extracts the stream function from the StreamFunction arrow defined as:

```
newtype SF a b = SF {runSF :: [a]->[b]}
```

And delay is defined as:

```
delay x = SF (init . (x:))
```

SF is an instance of ArrowChoice (which declares mapA) and thus an instance of Arrow.

## My Understanding

```
mapA :: arr a b -> arr [a] [b]
delay :: SF a b
```

such that `delay` simply prepends its second argument with its first.

Thus, `mapA (delay 0)` should return us an SF arrow that takes `[[a]]` and returns `[[b]]`

```
mapA (delay 0) :: SF [[a]] [[b]]
```

I would expect that the "circuit" that this would result in is:

[image: Diagram of Control Flow of mapA (delay 0)]

Where the numbers label parts of the process:

1. For any non-empty `list x`, `listcase` will emit `Right(x, xs)`. For the empty list, `listcase` will emit `Left()`, the terminal case.
2. Values tagged `Right` will be passed to the lower portion. Values tagged `Left` will be passed to `const[]`, which essentially stops the iteration.
3. With input `(x, xs)`, `x` will be passed to `(delay 0)`, while `xs` will be passed back through to `listcase`.
4. The output of 3 will be `(z, zs)`, which gets passed to `uncurry (:)`, which joins the tuple back into the list.

Here’s my understanding of the flow, with input `[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]`:

- First pass

  1. `Right ([1,2,3],[[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])`
  2. `([1,2,3], [[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])` gets passed to the lower portion
  3. `(delay 0)` is called on `[1,2,3]`, resulting in `[0,1,2]`. `[[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]` is passed back to `listcase`
- Second pass

  1. `Right ([4,5,6], [[7,8,9]])`
  2. `([4,5,6], [[7,8,9]])` gets passed to the lower portion
  3. `(delay 0)` is called on `[4,5,6]`, resulting in `[0,4,5]`. `[[7,8,9]]` is passed back to `listcase`
- Third pass

  1. `Right ([7,8,9], [])`
  2. `([7,8,9], [])` gets passed to the lower portion
  3. `(delay 0)` is called on `[7,8,9]`, resulting in `[0,7,8]`. `[]` is passed back to `listcase`.
- Fourth pass

  1. `Left ()`, dropped on the floor.

At this point, we get to part 4, which takes the output of 3 and concats it all together. We essentially build of an operation of:

`[0,1,2] : [[0,4,5] : [[0,7,8] : []]]`

Which would give us `[[0,1,2],[0,4,5],[0,7,8]]`.

## My Confusion

Clearly, my above flow is wrong.

How does calling `runSF (mapA (delay 0)) [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]` result in `[[0,0,0],[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]`?

Comment: Well, clearly my understanding is off since delay's type is SF. Not a function itself.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I find these examples tricky to reason about. There are two lists in this
example, the outer list is the stream that your arrow operates over, while
the inner lists are what mapA maps over. Consider a simpler example so we
can ignore the recursive case for now. Given

```
runSF (mapA (delay 0)) [[1], [2]]
```

We see that the first step

1. Piping the input through the `listcase` arrow gives us the output
   `[Right (1, []), Right (2, [])]`. The first elements of each pair
   are fed to the `delay 0` arrow, while the second elements are fed
   back to `mapA f`.
2. So, we have that `[1, 2] => delay 0` and `[[], []] => mapA f`.
   Feeding `[1,2]` into `delay 0` gives the result `[0, 1]`, and
   feeding the empty lists to `mapA f` yields more empty lists
   `[[], []]`.
3. Those two results are fed to `arr (uncurry (:))`, which acts like `zipWith (:)`,
   since these functions are all mapped over lists, so it joins the two input
   lists element-wise.

   ```
   [0,  1]
      |
      v
   arr (uncurry (:)) => [ 0:[], 1:[] ] == [[0], [1]]
      ^
      |
   [[], []]
   ```

The key is to recognize that all the stuff constructed with `arr` operates on
the inner set of lists, so running your initial input through `arr listcase`
does not produce `Right ([1,2,3],[[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])`, but
`[Right (1, [2, 3]), Right (4, [5,6]), Right (7, [8,9])]`.
This is my attempt to draw it out in a diagram.

```
     [Right (1, [2, 3]), Right (4, [5,6]), Right (7, [8,9])]
     =======================================================
                 |        [1, 4, 7]      +-----------+ [0, 1, 4]
  +----------+   |       +----=--------->|   delay   |-----=------|
  | listcase |---=------>|               +-----------+            |   +-------------------+
  +----------+           |                                        +-->| arr (uncurry (:)) |---> [[0,0,0],[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
                         |                                        |   +-------------------+
                         |               +-----------+            |
                         +-------=------>|   mapA f  |------=-----|
                                 |       +-----------+      |
                                 |                          |
                          [[2,3],[4,5],[6,7]]         [[0,0], [2,3],[4,5]]
                                                      * what will be
                                                        returned if you
                                                        trace it through
```

Sorry that I can't draw this better. In effect, `mapA` gives a transposed view
of the input list, so you can think of `mapA (delay 0)` as operating like
`transpose . map (init . (0:)) . transpose`, since `init . (0:)` is the
definition of `delay`.

Comment: Thanks a ton! Yes, I realize now that I was completely overlooking that listcase was being lifted into an SF arrow. Your diagramming and simple walkthrough made this very helpful. Thank you!

Comment: Finally... All that mess has been dissected to the core.. :) Many many thanks!!! You described the main mistake - wrong interpretation of what the `listcаse` does (I payed no attention to the fact that `listcase` being promoted to `SF` just maps itself to every element of the input list) - after clarifying this fact everything became sorted out..